# Custom NSView Drag and Drop images

Tags: image, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsview

I'm working on an OS X App and, I can't seem to get Drag and Drop to work. I've Googled a lot, but most posts about this subject are at least a few years old and none of them tells me the missing link I have in my thoughts.

Anyway, here is what I'm trying to do. I have an image somewhere on my desktop and I want the ability to drag and drop that into my Custom NSView. The custom view is a child object of a custom NSView named CircularImageView and is layer backed and only shows a circular shaped image on the screen.

Here's the code:

```
import Cocoa
import MCTools

@objc public protocol DragAndDropCircularImageViewDelegate {
    func imageDumped(sender: AnyObject!)
}

@IBDesignable @objc public class DragAndDropCircularImageView: CircularImageView {
    // This class provides the Drag And Drop Feature to the CircularImageView Class.

    // MARK: New in this class

    var highlight: Bool = false
    public var delegate: DragAndDropCircularImageViewDelegate?

    private func registerForDraggedImages() {
        self.registerForDraggedTypes(NSImage.imageTypes())
    }

    // MARK: CircularImageView Stuff

    public override var image: NSImage? {
        didSet {
            if let newImage = image {
                delegate?.imageDumped(self)
            }
        }
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.registerForDraggedImages()
    }

    public override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.registerForDraggedImages()
    }

    public override func updateLayer() {
        super.updateLayer()

        if highlight == true {

        }
    }

    // MARK: NS Dragging Destination Protocol

    public override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        // When a drag enters our drop zone.
        if NSImage.canInitWithPasteboard(sender.draggingPasteboard()) {
            if ((sender.draggingSourceOperationMask().rawValue & NSDragOperation.Copy.rawValue) > 0) {
                highlight = true
                self.needsLayout = true

                sender.enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions(.Concurrent, forView: self, classes: [NSPasteboardItem.self], searchOptions: [NSPasteboardURLReadingContentsConformToTypesKey: self], usingBlock: { (draggingItem, idx, stop) -> Void in

                    return
                })
            }
            return NSDragOperation.Copy
        }
        return NSDragOperation.None
    }

    public override func draggingExited(sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        // When drag exits our drop zone remove highlight of the drop zone.
        println("\(self)draggingExited")
        highlight = false
        self.needsLayout = true
    }

    public override func prepareForDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        // Update view for hovering drop.
        println("\(self)prepareForDragOperation")
        highlight = false
        self.needsLayout = true
        // Can we accept the drop?
        return NSImage.canInitWithPasteboard(sender.draggingPasteboard())
    }

    public override func performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        // Handle the drop data.
        println("\(self)performDragOperation \(sender)")
        if NSImage.canInitWithPasteboard(sender.draggingPasteboard()) {
            self.image = NSImage(pasteboard: sender.draggingPasteboard())
        }
        return true
    }

    // MARK: Interface Builder Stuff
}
```

I have seen some posts that I should be using:

```
self.registerForDraggedTypes([NSFilenamesPboardType])
```

instead of:

```
self.registerForDraggedTypes(NSImage.imageTypes())
```

But this doesn't seem to work in my case, when I'm using NSFileNamesPboardType I get the following debug message even before any of the NSDraggingDestination protocol messages have been called:

```
2015-05-07 11:07:19.583 CircularImageViewTest[44809:14389647] -[CircularView.DragAndDropCircularImageView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000166d80
(lldb) p 0x608000166d80
(Int) $R0 = 106102873550208
```

I don't understand how this works. Somewhere the frameworks try to copyWithZone on an integer? Can anyone explain this to me?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the code below works. It was all caused by sender.enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions in draggingEntered. Something goes wrong in the Apple frameworks when it is called.

```
import Cocoa
import MCTools

@objc public protocol DragAndDropCircularImageViewDelegate {
    func imageDumped(sender: AnyObject!)
}

@IBDesignable @objc public class DragAndDropCircularImageView: CircularImageView {
    // This class provides the Drag And Drop Feature to the CircularImageView Class.

    // MARK: New in this class

    var highlight: Bool = false
    public weak var delegate: DragAndDropCircularImageViewDelegate?

    private func registerForDraggedImages() {
//        self.registerForDraggedTypes(NSImage.imageTypes())
        self.registerForDraggedTypes([NSFilenamesPboardType])
    }

    // MARK: CircularImageView Stuff

    public override var image: NSImage? {
        didSet {
            if let newImage = image {
                delegate?.imageDumped(self)
            }
        }
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.registerForDraggedImages()
    }

    public override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.registerForDraggedImages()
    }

    public override func updateLayer() {
        super.updateLayer()

        if highlight == true {

        }
    }

    // MARK: NS Dragging Destination Protocol

    public override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        // When a drag enters our drop zone.
        if NSImage.canInitWithPasteboard(sender.draggingPasteboard()) {
            if ((sender.draggingSourceOperationMask().rawValue & NSDragOperation.Copy.rawValue) > 0) {
                highlight = true
                self.needsLayout = true
            }
            return NSDragOperation.Copy
        }
        return NSDragOperation.None
    }

    public override func draggingExited(sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        // When drag exits our drop zone remove highlight of the drop zone.
        println("\(self)draggingExited")
        highlight = false
        self.needsLayout = true
    }

    public override func prepareForDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        // Update view for hovering drop.
        println("\(self)prepareForDragOperation")
        highlight = false
        self.needsLayout = true
        // Can we accept the drop?
        return NSImage.canInitWithPasteboard(sender.draggingPasteboard())
    }

    public override func performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        // Handle the drop data.
        println("\(self)performDragOperation \(sender)")
        if NSImage.canInitWithPasteboard(sender.draggingPasteboard()) {
            self.image = NSImage(pasteboard: sender.draggingPasteboard())
            self.delegate!.imageDumped(self)
        }
        return true
    }

    // MARK: Interface Builder Stuff
}
```